# How to rest only one value of an object inside an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. All of the objects have these keys and values :

```
const arr=[ { name: 'beer', amount: 50, price: 50 }]


function changeValue(){

// here I would like to receive back an array with the same object keys and values except amount.
// arr.amount should be 0
}

<button onclick='changeValue()'> Reset Amount </button>
```

How can I get back the same exact array with same objects, except the amount should be 0 for each one? I think this can be possible be done with the spread operator.

Comment: But amount is already 0?

Comment: @Aplet123 Sorry forgot to change that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use rest parameters.

```js
const arr=[ { name: 'beer', amount: 100, price: 50 }, { name: 'test', amount: 50, price: 10 }];
const res = arr.map(({amount, ...rest})=>({...rest, amount: 0}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the original array

```js
function changeValue(something){
   return arr.map( it => ({
        ...it, 
        amount: something
   }))
}
```

You may also want to filter the `it` based on some criteria